# CSS propreties for first element of all HTML-tree

Tags: css, image, css-selectors

I have the following html

```
<div class="text">
    <p>
        <img ...> //properties are needed only for this
    </p>
    <img ...>
    <figure>
        <img ...>
    </figure>
    <p>
        <img ...>
    </p>
    <p>
        <figure>
            <img ...>
        </figure>
    </p>
</div>
```

```css
div.text img:first-of-type {
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
    <p>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/aaa/fff">
    </p>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/aaa/fff">
    <figure>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/aaa/fff">
    </figure>
    <p>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/aaa/fff">
    </p>
    <p>
        <figure>
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/aaa/fff">
        </figure>
    </p>
</div>
```

First img may be children of *div* or wrapped in *p*, *figure*.

How can I add CSS-propreties for first *img* in **ALL TREE** of *div.text*?

Comment: `.text > img:first-child` or if you are wanting each first image, remove the `>`, the question is a bit unclear as to what you want

Comment: I want only first in ALL TREE, not for EACH first

Comment: What does ALL TREE mean?  Just putting it in bold and capitols doesn't make it any clearer.  Anyway, if you only want the first one, then it's in my comment above

Comment: Thank you. The question has been edited for clarify

Comment: Ok now you have edited with the extra p at the top, you probably want to use `.text img:first-of-type` - it will get you the first image tag within the text div

Comment: `:first-of-type` get all wrapped *img*. In my example - will get all *img*.

Comment: How to get only the first *img* in my example?

Comment: Snippet was added

Comment: you may need to cancel all following images then:  https://jsfiddle.net/u0nayjre/ although if an image isn't in the first element at the top of the div, you may need to use a js solution (or just add a class to the one you want to style)

Comment: Wow. It's solved. Thank you very much!!!